# Perl regular expression for English word

Tags: regex, perl, words

I need a regular expression that will find anything that looks like an English word. In particular, I want the expression to match when a string has:

1) only letters; and

2) at least two *different* letters. (I am purposely excluding one-letter words.)

So I'm looking for something that would match `the` and `abracadabra` but not `aaa`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: ["aa" is an English word](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aa).

Comment: Sure, but when was the last time you used it in a sentence?

Comment: So the question you're really asking is, "what is a regular expression to match anything that looks like an English word that I might have used in a sentence a few times over the past few years or so?" This question is silly.

Comment: Never, but now that I know the word exists, I am totally using it the next time I play Scrabble.

Comment: @Tomalak: Actually, the question was pretty specific. It was "What is a regular expression that matches these two rules?" The answer below is useful; your comment isn't.

Comment: @itzy This comment wasn't particularly useful either. Thanks for playing.

Comment: "when was the last time you used it in a sentence"

aa... don't remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `\b(\w*(\w)\w*(?!\2)\w+)\b` works for you. It handles the examples you give.

It matches a letter `\w` in a group, then looks for something other than than letter using backreferences and negative lookahead `(?!\2)`. We match at least one character at the end, which is necessary to make the negative lookahead force at least one distinct character. Then we place additional `\w*`'s around to allow additional letters. `\b` assures the ends of the matches are at word boundaries.

http://www.rubular.com/r/pwjGi9eLf5

Please note that this is no super duper regular expression that matches English-only words. For that, you want to compare against a dictionary. But that doesn't seem to be what you're looking to do here.

Comment: Great, thanks. I didn't know how to do the negative look-ahead with a reference to a previous match. Very useful! For my purposes I just need to get rid of things that clearly aren't words. I'm not too concerned if it's actually a word or not, so this works perfectly.

Comment: @itzy seeing as you were unaware of negative look-ahead matches (not putting you down, just saying) and as I am trying to be the perldoc cheerleader: may I recommend you check out `perldoc perlrequick` and `perldoc perlreref` to see what other useful Perl regex tools might help you. Also useful are: the full `perldoc perlre` and the handy `perldoc perlrebackslash`.

Comment: English words may contains dashes, apostrophes, and various diacritics. I have a semistandard torture-test sentence for this sort of thing: "James's brother asked, \x{201C}\x{2019}Tis Ren\x{E9}e\x{2019}s and Noe\x{308}l\x{2019}s great\x{2010}grandparents\x{2019} 1970's-ish summer\x{2010}house, t'isn\x{2019}t it?\x{201D} Receiving no answer, he shook his head--and walked away."

Comment: How to match the `anti-virus`, `non-stop` word with `-` in the middle?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Lingua::EN::Splitter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aSplitter):

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Lingua::EN::Splitter qw(words);

my @words = words $input_text;
print @words;
```